# Is this a capacitor start motor and can I start it with a microwave capacitor

Tags: capacitor, motor

I salvaged an old motor out of a air conditioner and I want to know if it's a capacitor start motor if I can start it with the capacitor I have and how to start it.  I included pictures of the motor and capacitor btw i have never worked with capacitive start motors so i need details on exactly how to wire it up with out ruining it
[image: the capacitor]

[image: the motor]

Comment: why are you not reading the label on the motor? ... the answer to your questions is printed on the label

Comment: If it is a capacitor-start motor you likely connect one AC line to one of the speeds and the other to YL. The marked value of the capacitor is quite low for capacitor starting. After the motor reaches the normal operating speed, connect OR to YL. The A/C probably made that connection based on time or reduction in current. Hot should be connected to the line that has the thermal protection, likely the speed connection. Speed control is highly dependent on the motor being connected to the load it was designed for. You will likely see very little speed change with no load.

Comment: If you try the motor, measure the current that it takes. If it takes more than the 1.8 A marked after coming up to speed, disconnect it. All anyone can do is guess. That is why the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can read the motor specs, it requires a 6uF capacitor. Your 1uF capacitor that is salvaged from a microwave oven is therefore not suitable.

Comment: any idea where i can get a capacitor that would work and how to wire it up

Comment: go to an electrical supplier, or connect 6 microwave capacitors in parallel.

Comment: no one that is rated for that motor and again how to wire it up

Comment: @kevpar look at the label on the motor

Comment: yes but what wire do i connect to neutral one of the speed wires? the orange wire or the yellow wire? and how do i wire the capacitor up to it I'm not familiar with variable speed motors or capacitive start motors and this combines the two I'm sorry

Comment: I'd suggest the orange. The capacitor wires to the orange and yellow - that's what the diagram says.

Comment: Thank you but do I connect neutral to the speed wires or to capacitor wires like I said I don't know these motors would really help if I had a wiring diagram

Comment: and I've been told by a friend that this motor may not switch the capacitor out of the circuit whenever it starts running and the blow the capacitor is he right as I said this was taken out of an old air conditioning unit and all control Electronics were too badly damaged to figure out