# Is this a capacitive start motor and can i start it with this capacitor

Tags: capacitor, motor

I salvaged an old motor out of a air conditioner and I want to know if it's a capacitor start motor if I can start it with the capacitor I have and how to start it.  I included pictures of the motor and capacitor btw i have never worked with capacitive start motors so i need details on exactly how to wire it up with out ruining it if some one could make a diagram of how to do it that would be very helpful
[image: the capacitor]

[image: the motor]

Comment: Didn't we [see this before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/558369/38098)? I think the *powers here* prefer that you edit your earlier question and make additions there. Just FYI.

Comment: The capacitor says 1 uF, the label of the motor says 6 uF. Doesn't sound like those numbers match to me.

Comment: no because i don't know how to wire everything up and the other post would not reopen

Comment: Look at my comments to the closed question.

Comment: you are very very helpful thank you for nicely telling me what i need to do

Comment: *You* don't reopen a question on Stackexchange.  You look at why it was closed, then you edit it to fix the problems, if possible.  Then StackExchange solicits experienced members to weigh in on whether the question should be reopened (which does happen, regularly).

Comment: ok im new (if you couldn't tell)

Answer (score 1):

Spike closed the other question for lack of clarity.

You may find 6 uF film caps like this or close to it in any machine parts distributor. Schematics for “Start and Run” caps are easily findable and  intended to compensate for the poor power factor in each state.

The start cap also reduces the grid voltage drop by boosting a power factor corrected current from the start capacitor which is no longer needed at some inertial switch RPM and the Run Cap is optional but may improve  performance under dynamic load changes as well as reduce grid apparent current by compensating for the Reactance.

But since it is a rather small motor, (low current rating) I wouldn’t worry about a Run cap.

Comment: thank you you actually told me everything I needed to know and i believe that the cap connected to the yellow wire is the built in run cap am i correct